# In proving G contains an element of order 15 if contains normal subgroups of orders 3 and 5, respectively, is $HK$ itself cyclic with order 15?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

There is an answer here, but it is a "roadmap". [group containing normal subgroups of orders $3$ and $5$ contains element of order $15$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733735/group-containing-normal-subgroups-of-orders-3-and-5-contains-element-of-orde) There are answers here, but they are "roadmaps" too. [If $G$ contains normal subgroups of prime orders $p$ and $q$, then $G$ contains an element of order $pq$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471313)

In the proofs given by Brian Bi linked [here](http://brianbi.ca/artin/2.11) and by Alec Mouri linked [here](https://github.com/AMouri/artin-algebra/tree/master/Chapter%202%20-%20Groups/Section%208%20-%20Products%20of%20Groups), it is concluded that $HK$ is a subgroup and is isomorphic to $H \times K$ and then that $HK$ contains an element of order 15.

1. Is it correct that it is either:

   - that the reason $HK$ contains an element of order 15 is that $HK$ is cyclic with order 15 or
   - that that's not reason $HK$ contains an element of order 15, but $HK$ is still cyclic with order 15?
2. Actually, are groups isomorphic to cyclic groups also cyclic with the same order?

I know if images of cyclic groups under surjective homomorphisms are cyclic, but I didn't think they would be of different orders if we also assume injective.

The following are screenshots of the proofs mentioned above (Kiefer Sutherland's voice)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you've proved that $HK\simeq H\times K$, you know that $H$ is the product of two groups of prime order, hence $H$ and $K$ are abelian (cyclic) groups, and as their orders are coprime, you can apply the *Chinese remainder theorem*, which asserts the product is cyclic with order the product of the orders of each factor.

Comment: Bernard, thank you! Is there some immediately obvious way to show $HK$ contains an element of order 15 other than saying that $H \times K$ contains an element of order 15?

Comment: Using the reverse isomorphism of the Chinese remainder theorem: of $a$ has order $3$ and $b$ has order $5$, the pair $(3,5)$ has order $15$ (in $H\times K$), and its image by the reverse isomorphism (in multiplicative notation) is $a^{-5}b^6$ (based on *Bézout's identity*: $\;2\cdot 3-5=1$), which can be simplified to $ab$.

Comment: My question is incorrect. Do you think the proofs conclude $HK$ contains an element of order 15 because $HK$ is cyclic with order 15?

Comment: Oh! I had misunderstoog. Yes, that's the reson why. The product of two cyclic groups of coprime orders is cyclic.

Comment: Bernard, no no I was confusing. Thank you so so much!